# excel vba: How to Sort Group of Row based on column value

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have the following data in my excel. and my requirements is to sort a group of rows based on Forecast Age in Descending order. I have already tried the built in sort function in excel but it doesn't meet my requirements.

Let's say for example my forecast age is in `Range("BO54")`=17 and `Range("BO88")`=19,    `Range("BO88")` value is bigger than the other so it should to be on the top.  `Range("BO88")`'s group is `Range("A78:CA91")` .

In short I want 88th row and it's group of row which is `Range("A78:CA91")` to be at the top. Is there a way to do this without sorting the data within `Range("A78:CA91")`?

[image]

Comment: You do not want to sort the data in Range ("A78:CA91") and you want 88th row to be on the top. Please be more informational

Comment: i'm sorry if my explanation is not clear..yes i don't want `Range("A78:CA91")` to be sort.. and i want 88th row and its group of row which is `Range("A78:CA91")` to be at the top...

Comment: Oh so you want to check the Forecast Age of every group (based on "house" column) and move those group of rows move up or down

Comment: I think your best bet would be to make use of a helper column. Or in this case three. First decide which column you want to sort upon. Then have a column filled with the number for `Forecast Age` throughout the block of that specific House. You could do a loop in VBA that assigns the same number untill the value of `House` changes. Then also add a second helper column that is always 12,11,10.. etc. for the different rows within one `House`. The third row is just a `Concatenate` of the previous two. Most Likely you could also do this in one row with VBA. Then just sort on your helper row.

Comment: If you want you can even dedicate a cell in your header on on a seperate sheet to assign first a value for the date it needs to look up. In your current case `17dec15` as that is the value of `BO1`. Then let it loop through the `Range("F1", Range("F1").End(xlToRight))` to find a match, and use the column for the routine I desribed earlier.

Comment: @Luuklag I don't get what u mean...

Comment: Let me simplify then. Take for example column F and G. In column F you put for every instance of House the value you want to sort upon. So in this case for all rows of House 07 you put 17 and for all rows of House 09 you put 19. In column G you put the values from 12 to 1 for each instance of House. So the row where `Plan/actual Harvest QTY` is becomes 12, and `Forecast female weight` becomes 1. Then you can just use the sort of excel to first sort on F and then on G both in Descending order. You can assign these values either manually, or let VBA do it for you.

Comment: but there might be another farm house that will have similar age...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I can suggest you one way which might be lengthy to code.

First you can run a loop on all rows with a condition that if `"Description" = "Forecast Age"` then paste it in a new sheets. This will give you list of rows with every `"house"` and `age`. `Sort` it based on age and add a column which will assign `rank()` it based on age.

After this add a rank column in your main data and `vlookup` the above obtained ranks to each house and then finally, sort the entire table based on these ranks. 
You should obtain the result you expect.

This is just a heads up. You can optimize the process and improvise it.

Comment: yeah i think that's a good idea... but wouldn't it make the program slower?