# VBA Custom Sorting with "Group-By"

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, group-by

I am new to writing VBA. I understand core programming concepts as I have a degree in programming, but again I am new to learning VBA syntax, the methods, their constants, limitations, just the whole 9.

The skinny on my issue: 
I am attempting to work in an auto-sort method, which I have. However, I need to group by one of three columns. My experience with SQL had me searching for a way to use group by on the column containing a date. But no dice.

Sample Data: (as desired result)

```
Column C        Column D    
02/1/2017      TRUCK   
02/1/2017      TRUCK  
02/1/2017      COLLECT  
02/1/2017      HOLLAND  
02/2/2017      TRUCK  
02/2/2017      TRUCK   
02/3/2017      TRUCK  
02/3/2017      COLLECT  
02/4/2017      COLLECT  
02/4/2017      HOLLAND  
02/4/2017      HOLLAND  
02/4/2017      HOLLAND
```

I have been looking for a while to resolve my issue - to no avail. Here is some of what I came across but I haven't yet found a solution.

This method in the below link doesn't work as it focuses on grouping rows to sort, where I want to group by a column containing the date:
[excel vba: How to Sort Group of Row based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328256/excel-vba-how-to-sort-group-of-row-based-on-column-value)

This method in this link looked like I would be able to get what I need, but no answer yet:
[Group and combine values in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871694/group-and-combine-values-in-vba)

This method would create groups in Excel. Close, but I want to group-by...This question should have been titled "Group with VBA"
[Group By With VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677715/group-by-with-vba)

I also found some info on ranking, but I struggled to see how to make that fit here.

Code I am running which works fine to sort but just isn't quite there. I need it to sort Column D while still keeping Column C in ascending order. Note that this code is a separate module I wrote to test how it worked. Please don't point out that I need to sort 3 columns but the below is referencing Column D only. I can put new ideas together with what I have to bring it all to light.

```
'method to sort values based on carriers defined in a custom list
'carriers are ordered by pickup times
'
Sub CustomSort()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort.SortFields.Add  Key:=Range("D:D"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
    "Truck,Collect,Holland,LME,YRC", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A3:Z9999")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Any tips to guide me in the right direction on my conundrum are greatly appreciated!

Apologies if this has already been asked and resolved - I couldn't seem to find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would help. We have no idea what your data looks like now and what you want it to look like

Comment: My apologies there - it would be for dates. As example: 2/1/2017, 2/2/2017, 2/3/2017. Multiple entries for each date. I want to keep all 2/1/2017 at the top, then follow with the mentioned custom sort values. Then followed by 2/2/2017 and the custom sort values again. Ultimately listing all oldest dates on top, with the coinciding custom sort as noted for each group of dates (such as for all 2/1/2017). Let me know if that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I still don't think what you're trying to achieve is clear.  Maybe you could edit your question to include some data from column D before sorting and how you would like it to look after the grouping.

Comment: J. Garth - I have edited to include an actual data sample. Custom sort as noted in above code is TRUCK, COLLECT, HOLLAND, etc. So, the sample shows I would like to use this custom order along with keeping dates in ascending order. Hope that clarifies for everyone.

Comment: We still don't know the issue. We only know "just isn't quite there". If you analysed your issue enough to provide a clear explanation you would most likely come up with a solution yourself

Comment: Seems like you just need to add a sort key first on ColC (to group the dates) and then a second sort keyon ColD (your custom order).  Did you try that?

Comment: Nick - I added more info to clarify the issue to any others trying to resolve their own problems.
 
Tim - Your suggestion works as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a sort as you describe, the macro recorder gave me this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort.SortFields.Clear

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort.SortFields.Add _
       Key:= Range("C2:C13"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= xlSortNormal

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort.SortFields.Add _
       Key:= Range("D2:D13"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
       Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder :="Truck,Collect,Holland,LME,YRC", _
       DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Outbound Work Status").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:E13")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Comment: Tim - that appears to be working as expected. Thank you. I hadn't tried it in this manner, so that was my issue. I tried it with another sort method for the date and another column, then this sort method for the custom sort on carrier (column D). Just couldn't get it to keep the dates together - looks like my original methods must have been flipping the sort when the custom carrier sort was being called. Thanks again.